# The sys.getrefcount print diff result, Anyone help me understand this result

Tags: python

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> python -V
Python 3.8.3
```

## A. result is  2

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = "test"
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.getrefcount(a))
2
```

## B.the result is 4

```
[ cat .\main.py ]
import sys
a = "test"
print(sys.getrefcount(a))

python main.py
4
```

## C. result is 3

```
[cat .\demo.py]
import main

python demo.py
3
```

Anyone help me understand this result ? thks !!!

Comment: Why are you doing this as `Administrator`? Do your Python learning under your ordinary user account and keep Administrator for when you actually need to modify the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a value which can only be evaluated at run-time, e.g.:

```
x = "te"
y = "st"
a = x + y
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
```

then you should get 2.

Bear in mind also what the doc string (seen in `help(sys.getrefcount)`) says regarding one of those two references.

```
getrefcount(...)
    getrefcount(object) -> integer
    
    Return the reference count of object.  The count returned is generally
    one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary)
    reference as an argument to getrefcount().
```

So one of these two references is the variable `a`, and the other one is the temporary reference described.

If instead of the above you use a compile-time immutable constant:

```
a = "test"
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
```

the count may be higher, to allow for reuse of constants, but this is an implementation detail.  There is no reason to care about the reference count of constants in your code, because they are not objects that you would expect to be able to destroy.

---

Note: I suppose that it is possible that even at run-time, the compiler *could* choose to try to re-use references to strings, and that the first example could give a value greater than 2 if the constant `"test"` is used in some module that has been imported.  This seems unlikely because it would slow down calculations for a relatively small gain.  But if you still see a result greater than 2 with the first example, try changing the values of `x` and `y`, so that your variable `a` has a value not used anywhere else.